# Cross Compile gsoap 2.8. for arm

Tags: linux, arm, gsoap

i want to cross compile gsoap for arm-linux and this is my configuration command

`./configure CC="arm-linux-gcc" CROSS_COMPILER="arm-linux-" ARCH="arm" --host=arm-linux LR="arm-linux-lr" LD="arm-linux-ld" LDFLAGS="-static" --enable-static --enable-samples --disable-openssl --prefix=/usr/local/gsoap-2.8 CXX="arm-linux-g++"`

and i get this error after running **make** 

`arm-linux-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -DWITH_YACC -DWITH_LEX  -DSOAPCPP_IMPORT_PATH="\"/usr/local/gsoap-2.8/share/gsoap/import\"" -DLINUX -g -O2 -MT soapcpp2-soapcpp2_yacc.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/soapcpp2-soapcpp2_yacc.Tpo -c -o soapcpp2-soapcpp2_yacc.o test -f 'soapcpp2_yacc.c' || echo './'soapcpp2_yacc.c
mv -f .deps/soapcpp2-soapcpp2_yacc.Tpo .deps/soapcpp2-soapcpp2_yacc.Po
/bin/bash ../../ylwrap soapcpp2_lex.l .c soapcpp2_lex.c -- /bin/bash /home/glassess/local/arm/gsoap-2.8/missing --run flex

make[4]: * [soapcpp2_lex.c] Error 1`

so whats wrong,i must compile yacc and bison my self for arm-linux

Comment: compile dont need continue more for me because i just need lib file and its create before that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compile dont need continue more for me, because i just need lib file and its create before this error

Answer (score 1):

> so whats wrong,i must compile yacc and bison myself for arm-linux

You need to install flex for your build environment in order to be able to be executed by make (then not the cross-compiled one).

When I cross compile gSOAP the build output looks like:

```
/bin/bash ../../ylwrap soapcpp2_lex.l lex.yy.c soapcpp2_lex.c -- flex  -l
```

In yours there is no flex command.
Probably configure flex detection failed. 
You probably need to check if flex is available from your build environement, running `flex -h` or `which flex`.

Comment: appreciate for your comment but I had them